# Paramiko 2 tier cisco SSH

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I am attempting to write a python script to SSH into a cisco device to run a list of commands using the **paramiko** module. The tricky part here is that it has 2 levels of authentication where I will log in intially with a primary password then enable the device so I have the necessary permissions to run my commands

So far I have the following code but I am getting an error as I attempt to run my command

```
import sys                                                                                                                                                                                                              
sys.stderr = open('/dev/null')
import paramiko as pm
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
deviceip='deviceip'
#SSH into device using ip
cmd='sh int description | e down'
client = pm.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AllowAllKeys())
client.connect(deviceip, username="username", password="pass", allow_agent=False,look_for_keys=False)
chan = client.invoke_shell()
chan.send('enable')
chan.send('enable password')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
```

Below is an example of me attempting to manually run my code in console.

```
>>> client.connect(deviceip, username="user", password="pass",  allow_agent=False,look_for_keys=False)
>>> chan = client.invoke_shell()
>>> chan.send('en')
2
>>> chan.send('enable pass')
12
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/client.py", line 307, in exec_command
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 541, in open_session
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 647, in open_channel
paramiko.ssh_exception.ChannelException: (4, 'Resource shortage')
```

At the moment I do not understand the Exception it raises and or why the error is caused.

*****UPDATE******

I am able to send commands directly to the command line in using a channel. This is my current solution however it is rather hackish. I believe the overarching problem resides with CISCO devices. In my research I have found that they only allow 1 command per session.

The code below is an example of my usage.

```
client = pm.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AllowAllKeys())
client.connect(deviceip, username="user", password="pass", allow_agent=False,look_for_keys=False)
chan = client.invoke_shell()
time.sleep(1)
chan.send('en\n')
chan.send('pass2\n')
time.sleep(1)
chan.send(cmd+'\n')
time.sleep(1)
output = chan.recv(9999)
interfaces=[]
#Get Interface information
for line in output.splitlines()[4:]:
   newline=line.split()
```

If anyone finds a better solution please let me know if would be much easier to uses paramiko built in function such as client.exec_command(cmd)